# What does “If OAuth is used, the delete_repo scope is required.“ mean in GitHub API?

Tags: git, api, github, octokit

I want to use GitHub api to delete a repo, I also tried Octokit, but not work at all, there is a sentence I can't understand in the document, “If OAuth is used, the delete_repo scope is required.“, I can't get its point here, please help me, thanks!

https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#delete-a-repository

**Delete a Repository**

> Deleting a repository requires admin access. If OAuth is used, the
>   delete_repo scope is required.

DELETE /repos/:owner/:repo
Response

> Status: 204 No Content X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000 X-RateLimit-Remaining:
>   4999

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the option here:
https://github.com/settings/applications

The permission of access tokens

Sorry to waste the resource to ask this question here ...